# How to use sha256sum --check option to fail if incorrect hash on a docker script

Tags: bash, shell, docker, sha256, sha

I'm writing a docker script and therefore I cannot rely on bash scripts. I need the docker script to fail if the sha256sum of a downloaded file (though wget) hash is incorrect. I see that there exists a check option in sha256sum, but I can't find how to use it.

It's something like `sha256sum -c hash file` but it won't work for me. I think I actually must supply a file to -c, something like using echo.

Comment: Which part of the man page are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Examples:

```
sha256sum /etc/passwd > checksum
sha256sum -c checksum
```

Output:

```
/etc/passwd: OK
```

or

```
sha256sum /etc/passwd > checksum
sha256sum --status -c checksum
echo "$?"
```

Output:

```
0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of `sha256sum -c` used with a file.

```
echo "68a2297eb099d1a76097905a2ce334e3155004ec08cdea85f24527be3c48e856  go1.13.linux-amd64.tar.gz"|sha256sum -c -
```

go1.13.linux-amd64.tar.gz: OK

You pass in the *checksum space filename* as the above example shows for go1.13.

Comment: You could also avoid the `-`  for standard input at the end; `echo " ... ..." | sha256sum -c` works to the same effect for me. See also https://superuser.com/a/1312747/491642